# i want to convert json to a compatible dart format help me i'm beginner in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

i'm learning flutter & dart and i was trying to implement state management and REST API data in the exercice but i got the same error since 2 days. My process is the same with the tutorail [tutorial link](https://youtu.be/x4DydJKVvQk) but i got a mistake somewhere
there is my Data service

```
import 'dart:convert';

import 'package:flutter_cubit/model/data_model.dart';
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;

class DataServices {
  String baseUrl = "https://61f969ae69307000176f7243.mockapi.io";
  Future<List> getInfo() async {
    var apiUrl = '/DevMobile';
    http.Response res = await http.get(Uri.parse(baseUrl + apiUrl));

    try {
      if (res.statusCode == 200) {
        List<dynamic> list = json.decode(res.body);
        print('donnees service non formaté $list');
        return list.map((e) => DataModel.fromJson(e)).toList();
      } else {
        return <DataModel>[];
      }
    } catch (e) {
      //print(e);
      return <DataModel>[];
    }
  }
}
```

and the Data Model

```
class DataModel {
  String name;
  String img;
  int price;
  int people;
  int stars;
  String description;
  String location;
  dynamic createdAt;

  DataModel({
    required this.name,
    required this.img,
    required this.price,
    required this.people,
    required this.stars,
    required this.description,
    required this.location,
  });

  factory DataModel.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    return DataModel(
      name: json["name"],
      img: json["img"],
      price: json["price"],
      people: json["people"],
      stars: json["stars"],
      description: json["description"],
      location: json["location"],
    );
    print('Données du model $DataModel');
  }
}
```

after a lot of print to know where is the problem it shown that all of the data disapear on the data Service just when i do `list.map((e) => DataModel.fromJson(e)).toList();`
i do everything like in the tutorial but it don't work.

thank for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**DataModel** class contains price field which is **int** but api gives you in the form of **String** so either you parse it into int or Change the type to **String**

```
String price;
```

**--------OR--------**

change fromJson method to

```
factory DataModel.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    return DataModel(
      name: json["name"],
      img: json["img"],
      price: num.parse(json["price"]).toDouble(), // here it is changed
      people: json["people"],
      stars: json["stars"],
      description: json["description"],
      location: json["location"],
    );
  }
```

Just copy and paste it.

Also Change **price** type to dobule as it is converted to `double`

```
double price
```